# Read value from List<List<Word>>

Tags: c#, list, tessnet2

I have following code in my C# project:

```
List<List<Word>> RecognizedPlates = 
DetectLicensePlate(img, licensePlateImagesList, filteredLicensePlateImagesList, licenseBoxList);
foreach (List<Word> W in RecognizedPlates)
{
     richTextBox1.Text = W.ToString();
}
```

could anyone please help to read text from `List<List<Word>> RecognizedPlates`
I get nothing in richTextBox after execution this code.

Comment: What's is the `Word`? Furthermore, since you make a foreach, only the the last `Word` would be presented in the `richTextBox1` text at the end. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: " I get nothing in richTextBox after execution this code.", make sure you are getting back some data in your list, otherwise you should end up with something like `System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Word]`, *which is another problem*.

Comment: @Christos Word comes from Tessnet2.Word, I am trying to read whole content from 'RecognizedPlates'

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make a big string from a list containing lists of words, use `string.Join`, like this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", RecognizedPlates.Select(list =>
    string.Join(" ", list)
));
```

This would produce a string with the content of individual lists joined by spaces, separated by `'\n'` characters. For example, a list of lists like this

```
{{"quick", "brown"}, {"fox", "jumps", "over"}, {"the", "lazy", "dog"}}
```

will be converted to this:

```
quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog
```